# OpenLayers: Problems adding WMS layer to OSM

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, openstreetmap, wms

I need to create a map with two layers. The first layer (basemap) is the OSM layer, and the second layer is my custom GeoServer WMS layer. This layer is in EPSG:4326 projection. Is this possible?

I have read many posts but I didn't solve my problem. I don't find this GeoServer layer in my map.

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map'{projection:"EPSG:900913",
                               maxResolution:2319.89824519781,
                               units:'m' }); 

osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map"); 
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", "95.172.21.2:8080/geoserver/wms";,
                                 {layers: 'asl.caserta:distretti_4326',trasparent: true},
                                 {isBaseLayer: false}); 
map.addLayers([osm, wms]); 
map.setCenter( new OpenLayers.LonLat(14.22231, 41.26700).transform( new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject() ), 12 ); –
```

Comment: Welcome to the forum. As first suggestion I would like to tell you that you need to add your code to see what is going wrong there. With that people can suggest you solutions to circumvent the problems you encountered.

Comment: map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{projection : "EPSG:900913",maxResolution:2319.89824519781,units:'m' });

osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", "http://95.172.21.2:8080/geoserver/wms", {layers: 'asl.caserta:distretti_4326', trasparent: true},{isBaseLayer: false});
map.addLayers([osm, wms]);
        
  map.setCenter(
                new OpenLayers.LonLat(14.22231, 41.26700).transform(
                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    map.getProjectionObject()
                ), 12
            );

Comment: I don't use geoserver, so not sure if your problem is the ip you're using. But the code needs displayProjection below projection. There you need to use EPSG:4326

Comment: try adding http:// to "95.172.21.2:8080/geoserver/wms

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your code. Firstly, the map was not properly initialized. The Url of WMS service, as well as the `transparent` paramter was incorrect.

I have corrected the code. The following works for me:

```js
var map, layer;
function init(){
    var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

    map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map',{projection: mercator} );


    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map"); 
    map.addLayer(osm);
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("WMS", "http://95.172.21.2:8080/geoserver/wms",
                         {layers: 'asl.caserta:distretti_4326',transparent: true},
                         {isBaseLayer: false}); 
    map.addLayer(layer);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(14.22231, 41.26700).transform(geographic,mercator), 10); 
}
```